# How do you set the font size on a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uifont

I can't find a way to set the font size of the title in a custom `UIBarButtonItem`. The only way I can think of getting around this is to set it as an image, which I would like to avoid. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Here's a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421121/change-font-size-via-uibarbuttonitem-in-uitextview-works-just-once

Answer (score 82):

Objective-C:

```
NSUInteger fontSize = 20;
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

[item setTitle:@"Some Text"];
[item setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Swift:

```
let fontSize:CGFloat = 20;
let font:UIFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize);
let attributes:[String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName: font];
    
let item = UIBarButtonItem.init();
    
item.title = "Some Text";
item.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControlState.normal);
    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: You can also use the `UIAppearance` proxy to `setTitleTextAttributes`.

Comment: Minor note: the UITextAttributeFont key value has been deprecated in iOS 7, you can use NSFontAttributeName instead.

Comment: If you plan to open a popup or menu by taping the button, you should also set set text attributes for 'UIControlStateHighlighted'.

Answer (score 4):

As a concrete example of what [kennytm suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721564/2108547), you create the `UIBarButtonItem` with something like the following:

```
UILabel *txtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
txtLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
txtLabel.text = @"This is a custom label";
UIBarButtonItem *btnText = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:txtLabel] autorelease];
```

Then, you can add it as centered text on a `UIToolbar` with the following for example:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace1 = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace2 = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithItems:flexSpace1, btnText, flexSpace2, nil]];
```

(of course, to get proper formatting, the `rect` used  for initializing `txtLabel` and `toolBar` should be the proper sizes.... but that's another exercise.)

Comment: You can make it the correct size using [txtLabel sizeToFit]. As a side note I'm not sure if this method will retain the blue capsule background a button item, so you may have to use some custom graphics with it. But its your best bet since you can't actually set the font size of a bar button item if you initialize it with a title.

Comment: You should set the Frame-size of the label too. In my case no items where displayed because they initialized with width and height of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Create a UILabel and use `-initWithCustomView:`.

Comment: So do I pass the UIBarButtonItem into the UILabel and set the font normally? I might also have a problem with your method because I'm using Interface Builder to put the UIBarButtonItem into a UIToolbar.

Comment: use setTextAttributes:forState:

Answer (score 3):

**Swift5:**

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.onItemTapped))
let font:UIFont = UIFont(name: "", size: 18) ?? UIFont()
item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                     [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT-NAME" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title",
                                                     style: .plain,
                                                     target: nil,
                                                     action: nil)
let font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font]

barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .normal)
barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .selected)
```