# UIBarButton font size

Tags: iphone

How can I change the size of the font in a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720733/how-do-you-set-the-font-size-on-a-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: You can find a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225457/change-the-text-of-a-uilabel-uibarbuttonitem-on-a-toolbar-programmatically) (Sorry, I'd like to comment your post instead of answer it, but I don't have enough reputation for that).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this using the following code:

```
barButtonName.title = @"SOME TEXT TO DISPLAY";
[barButtonName setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15<=SIZE YOU WANT], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```